# I lose my TextField State when I switch another TextField

Tags: flutter, forms, dart

My problem is I have 2 different Text Fields.
[image: Image Screen Shot]

my problem is, when I focus another Text Field or Change State somehow (closing the keyboard for example) I lose entire input I entered previously. It is like setState() occurs and removes all data from page. I am sure it's controller-related problem. I created 2 different TextEditingController and passed same class.

I assigned unique key and still getting same error. What is the problem?

```
class FormSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _mailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  FormSection({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        CustomTextInput(
          placeholder: "E - Posta",
          controller: _mailController,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        CustomTextInput(
          placeholder: "Şifre",
          controller: _passwordController,
          isPassword: true,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ButtonBar(
          children: [
            LoginPageButtons(
              buttonText: "Üye Ol",
              buttonFunction: () {},
            ),
            LoginPageButtons(
              buttonText: "Giriş Yap",
              buttonFunction: () {
                signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    emailAddress: _mailController.text,
                    password: _passwordController.text);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Text Field class:

```
class CustomTextInput extends StatefulWidget {
  final String placeholder;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool? isPassword;

  CustomTextInput({
    Key? key,
    required this.placeholder,
    required this.controller,
    this.isPassword,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomTextInputState createState() => _CustomTextInputState();
}

class _CustomTextInputState extends State<CustomTextInput> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: MainTheme.secondaryColor, // Border color
          width: 2.0, // Border width
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0), // Border radius
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        key: widget.key, // Unique key for each TextFormField
        obscureText: widget.isPassword ?? false,
        controller: widget.controller,
        style: MainTheme.themeData.textTheme.displaySmall!
            .copyWith(color: MainTheme.thirdColor),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintStyle: MainTheme.themeData.textTheme.displaySmall!
              .copyWith(color: MainTheme.thirdColor),
          hintText: widget.placeholder, // Placeholder text
          border: InputBorder.none, // Remove the default underline border
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for Helping.
Thanks for Helping.

Comment: thanks for you attention, I solved. Solution is on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextEditingController is a variable you need to hold on to, that itself is state.

If you create a TextEditingController in a Stateless widget, it will constantly lose its state and the TextField will not behave.

So the simple solution is to convert your Stateless widget into a Stateful widget.